# Calculate:$y'$ for $y = x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}}$ and $y = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+....\infty}}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

(1) If  $y = x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}}$

(2) If $y = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+....\infty}}}}$

then find $y'$ in both cases

(3)If $ y= \sqrt{\tan x+\sqrt{\tan x+\sqrt{\tan x+\sqrt{\tan x+....\infty}}}}\ $ then find$\ (2y-1)\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: $lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}x^y=\infty$ when x>1. The ellipsis is enough to understand the nature of what you're saying.

Comment: For the record I believe the operation to which you are referring is called a `Power Tower`, not sure what the other one ("(2)") is called though...

Comment: @ Albert Renshaw thank you for your guidance

Comment: notation $....\infty$ looks weird for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$y = x^{x^{x^{x^{{.^{.^{.^{}}}}}}}} = x^{y}$

Take the log of both sides.

Then $\ln y = y \ln x$

$ \implies\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln x \frac{dy}{dx}  + \frac{y}{x}$

$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{y^{2}}{x(1-y \ln x)}$ and then substitute for $y$

Answer (score 16):

### Hint

1. $$ y = x^y $$
2. $$ y^2 = x + y $$

As mentioned in comments, to solve the first one; you might need to take a look at [some of the applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications) of [Omega Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: (Note that the first requires at least tacit use of the Lambert W function.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Example #3 in the applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_3) is the same.

Answer (score 6):

1. As $y=x^y = e^{y \log{x}}$, take derivatives of both sides:

$$y' = \left( \frac{y}{x} + y' \log{x} \right ) x^y$$

Solve for $y'$.

1. As $y^2 = x+y$, then a similar implicit differentiation as above yields

$$2 y \,y' = 1 + y'$$

Solve for $y'$.