# convergence of $ x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{}}}}}}}}$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

From the link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336482/calculatey-for-y-xxxxx-infty-and-y-sqrtx), the following question was asked:

> What is $y'$ if $y = x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{}}}}}}}}$?

The function looks interesting. Here is my questions:

> What is the domain and range of $y = x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{}}}}}}}}$ if $y$ is converges?

I tried using excel and it seems that if $0.09<x<1.44$, $y$ converges and its range is from 0.39 to 2.39.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html. The closed form of the function can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is converges for $e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{1/e}$.

$$
\begin{align}
e^{-e} \approx & \ \ 0.0659880358453125370767901875970, \\
e^{1/e} \approx & \ \ 1.4446678610097661336583391085964.
\end{align}$$

This is a result by Euler. You could read more about the problem at [*Tetration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) wikipedia article.

And for the range, we have the following.

$${}^{\infty}x = x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}} = \frac{W(-\ln{x})}{-\ln{x}}  ~,$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). From this we get that the range is between $1/e$ and $e$.

$$\begin{align}
1/e \approx & \ \ 0.367879441171442321595523770162, \\
e \approx & \ \ 2.718281828459045235360287471353.
\end{align}$$